# Angular adding space before and after object name in IE

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I have built a web page that works well in Chrome. However, in IE a space is being added before and after an objects name.

I have a function:

```
  changegroup(groupname){
    console.log("Group changed to", groupname)
    this.selecteddocs = [];
    if (groupname != "All Groups") {
      this.http.get("https://example.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Document Separator Barcodes')/items?$top=1000&$orderBy=DocumentGroup,Title&$filter=DocumentGroup eq '"+ groupname +"' or DocumentGroup eq 'Any'").subscribe(data => {
        console.log("items for", groupname);
        .....
      });
    }
    else {
      .....
  }
```

This is the HTML for the selection:

```
  <select class="form-control" (change)="changegroup($event.target.value)">
    <option>
      All Groups
    </option>
    <option *ngFor="let group of uniquegroups">
      {{group}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

In Chrome, `groupname` will log as `All Groups` making the function work properly but in IE `groupname` will log as  `All Groups`  with a space at the beginning and end of the object. I have enabled all the recommended polyfills. What can I do to solve this where it does not impact functionality on Chrome?

Comment: you can try with `groupname.trim()` at the beginning of the function

Comment: We have no idea where this value comes from, so we can't possibly answer.

Comment: Added the `select` HTML.

Comment: `<option value="All Groups">`, `<option *ngFor="let group of uniquegroups" [value]="group">`

Comment: @mr_sudaca That fixed my issue on both browsers. Thanks!

Comment: @JBNizet That fixed the issue and is probably the best method. Thank you.

Comment: @JBNizet Why does the first option have syntax of `value` and the second option has syntax of `[value]`?

Comment: Because "All Values" is a literal value that you want the value of the option to have, whereas group is an angular expression that must be evaluated, and the result of this evaluation must be the value of the option. That's fundamental angular stuff.